# Magento 1.9 - Discount Breakdown in Multiple Lines

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently looking for a way to display multiple discounts in separate lines in the Magento shopping cart without having to buy an extension..

Currently I have a negative discount applied as "Shipping Insurance" based on cart rules - example - if the subtotal is 2000-2500, add surcharge of $12.60 for shipping insurance.

**This part works fine...**

*Screenshots:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeOLF.jpg

**Now I want to offer the customer a 10% off coupon using code "10OFF"**

When applied, i'd like it to show up as a seperate line item and display the discount breakdown, but instead it gets combined into shipping insurance (my discount label)

**Is there any way to get it to break out in multiple lines?** To show Shipping Insurance as a surcharge on line 1, and the next line show the 10% Off discount calculation?

ex: 
Shipping Insurance: $XX.XX
10% Off discount: -$XX.XX

**I'm on magento 1.9.1.1 using the RWD theme.**

Anyone have experience doing so - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to do the same. Did you get it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156221)